# Is "Who do you take after to be good at Math?" fine?

Tags: grammaticality

Suppose that there are a mother and a son. The son is good at math at school. So his mother wants to know who her son takes after.

In this situation, can I ask like this?

> Who do you take after to be good at Math?

Is this a right sentence in terms of grammar?

Comment: you can use two spaces to start a new line: `There is a mother and a son.__`

Comment: Subject is a "Do-er" or what the sentence is about. Like @G.ANN said, "you" is the subject. We always use "who" when we refer to a subject of a clause and "whom" when referring to the object of a clause. i your sentence, the subject is "you,"  so you should use "whom" instead of "who."

Comment: Your sentence "Who do you take after to be good at Math? Sounds OK.

Answer (score 4):

It's close, and unremarkable in daily speech. Technically, it should be:

> Who*m* do you take after to be good at math?

- Who(m) is not the subject; "you" is.
- Note that I've lower-cased "math". This may be a U.S./BrE split.

Comment: I think BrE uses (or at least used to use) *maths*.

Comment: _Whom_ is more grammatically correct, and is therefore the better option in formal writing. In conversation, though, one might run the risk of sounding almost too formal.

Comment: BrE still uses *maths*, but only a tiny minority of Brits would use *whom* in the OP's sentence. The sentence is a bit strange in BrE, because "take after" usually refers to inherited *physical* attributes. A more idiomatic BrE version would be "Who did you get your maths ability from?" (or "Where", as in J.R's answer)

Comment: Similarly, only a tiny number of Americans would use whom. But the question was about grammar. :)
Note that some Americans (I believe this is regional) would use "favor" for the U.K. meaning of "take after". As in "he favors his father around the eyes, don't you think?"

Answer (score 3):

One way someone might ask this question is:

> **How did you become so good at math?**

Granted, there are a lot of ways to answer that question – practice, hard work, etc. But one could say:

> *I got that from my dad*.

If you wanted to be tongue-in-cheek, you could ask:

> **Where did you get your math gene from?**

Most native speakers would interpret that as a playful way to ask which family members were also good at math.

Answer (score 1):

"Who do you take after to be good at Math?" sounds really awkward to me. I think a more common phrasing would be something like

"From whom did you inherit your math skills?"

The way I would say it as a sloppy and casual native speaker would be, "Did you get your math skill from your mom or your dad?"